# How to generate entries for different mechanisms with saslpasswd2?

Tags: sendmail, sasl

I'm struggling to create the satisfactory set of records in `sasldb2.db`. If I use the regular

```
saslpasswd2 -c user
```

I get exactly one record, according to sasldblistusers2:

```
user@my.example.com:    userPassword
```

whereas [this page](http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/sasldb_configuration.html) leads me to believe, there ought to be a line for each mechanism (`DIGEST-MD5`, `CRAM-MD5`, and so on).

If I add `-n` to avoid storing the plain-text (I only really need the CRAM-MD5):

```
saslpasswd2 -n -c user
```

then sasldblistusers2 finds no records to list *at all*. My `saslpasswd.conf` consists of two lines:

```
mech_list:      cram-md5 digest-md5 ntlm plain
log_level:      9
```

I tried this on FreeBSD using cyrus-sasl-2.1.26_12 and Ubuntu with 2.1.25... What am I doing wrong?

---

I need `CRAM-MD5` because, without further reconfiguring, my sendmail only lists that and `DIGEST-MD5` as the acceptable `AUTH`-mechanisms. And the iPhones, apparently, do not support `DIGEST-MD5`. And I'm only doing all of this for the sake of a couple of iPhones -- the normal computers already authenticate themselves with the client SSL-certificates issued by my own authority.

---

Ok, apparently, the `CRAM-MD5` authentication has been succeeding all along -- despite not being listed by `sasldblistusers2`. I created a [new question](/questions/880547/) -- why does sendmail refuse relaying despite authentication's success.

Comment: I updated my question to answer yours. Now, can we, please, go back to the subject matter? Why is `saslpasswd2` not creating all of the records expected?

Comment: Iphones might work with `PLAIN`, but my sendmail does not offer it. Either way, `saslpasswd2` has to work and it does not. Can we talk about _that_, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe it’s a -u realm problem?

Comment: @eckes, at this point I'm willing to believe anything -- if _you_ manage to create a SASL db with a CRAM-MD5 entry for a user on your machine, do post the command line and, if I can reproduce it, I'll award you the bounty :)

Comment: The page you've linked to says right at the bottom in a highlighted section "In Cyrus-SASL-2.x users in sasldb2 are listed with sasldblistusers2 and the output will only produce one single line.", i.e. without the realms and mechanisms. Have you added `pwcheck_method: auxprop` and `auxprop_plugin: sasldb` to your SASL/Sendmail configuration?

Comment: @bodgit, I tried various settings but could not get the desired result. If you manage to do it -- and post the relevant config-file(s) and command-line, the bounty is yours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get it working with the following:

/etc/mail/sendmail.mc has the following set:

```
define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `13')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5')dnl
```

/etc/sasl2/Sendmail.conf contains the following:

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
mech_list:      cram-md5 digest-md5
log_level:      9
```

Add a user to /etc/sasldb2 with:

```
# saslpasswd2 -c -u mail.example.com -a Sendmail test
<password>
<password>
```

Then test with:

```
# sendmail -O LogLevel=14 -bs -Am
220 server.example.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.7/8.14.7; Tue, 24 Oct 2017 09:24:44 +0100
ehlo localhost
250-server.example.com Hello root@localhost, pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
AUTH CRAM-MD5
334 <challenge>
<generate response using test@mail.example.com, password and the above challenge text>
235 2.0.0 OK Authenticated
```

You can probably pare the settings down the absolute minimum but the above worked for me. This was on a RHEL 7 host.

Comment: Nope, not working... `sasldblistusers2` still only lists one entry and sendmail still rejects the iPhone with `403 4.7.0 not authenticated`.

BTW, _how_ do you "generate response" to a `CRAM-MD5` challenge?

Comment: I used http://busylog.net/cram-md5-online-generator/ to generate the response. With the logging in Sendmail increased as I did, you should see some sort of SASL messages indicating if the authentication was successful or not.